# Postfix smtp hook not working

Tags: postfix-mta

I am using a postfix hook to check every mail with a bash script.

I have this line in my master.cf

```
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd -o content_filter=myhook:dummy
```

My script is also called for outgoing emails, I want that the script is just called when I receive any email. How can I configure this?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your incoming and outgoing emails are sent to Postfix through the same process (`smtpd` using the `smtp` port: *25*).

So the [`content_filter`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#content_filter) is applied either way

One way to achieve your goal is to use another [`smtpd`](http://www.postfix.org/smtpd.8.html) process listening on an other port without the `content_filter`. In the [`master.cf`](http://www.postfix.org/master.5.html):

```
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd -o content_filter=myhook:dummy
1025      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
```

With this configuration:

- Every mail sent to the port *25* is filtered.
- Every mail sent to the port *1025* is not filtered